# Can I use compiler plugins on stable Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-compiler-plugin

The thing I'm trying to make requires plugin compiler, because I need error reporting at compile time, however I'd like for it to run on Rust stable and not just nightly.

Is there a way to run compiler plugins on stable Rust?

Comment: As of now, the discussion in the [plugin tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29597) indicates that the feature is on the table for deprecation and removal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not yet; compiler plugins rely on an `unstable` API that is very much in flux. While it's impossible to foretell when the APIs stabilize, I think we'll see a good number of Rust versions before those APIs can be declared stable.

A good workaround for things that only need ASTs is to use [syntex](https://crates.io/crates/syntex_syntax) and build your own program independent of rustc.

Comment: What about: https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/pre-rfc-stablized-syntax-extensions-sort-of/2259/12 ? Was there an effort to allow syntax extension exporting?

Comment: Yes, but it seems to be a) stalled, and b) severely limited.